# logstash + kibana + elasticsearch web issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have 2 elasticsearch nodes in an AWS EC2 environment and I'd like to use logstash + kibana on a separate logging server.
Logstash works as an indexer and is able to get the logs from the ES nodes (I'm still playing with how/what I need to log) The issue is with Kibana.

I'd like to be able to use Kibana on the logstash server to monitor the logs on my ES nodes. For example:
    ES nodes: 10.110.65.91/92
    Logstash/kibana 10.110.65.93

I'd like to be able to hit [http://10.110.65.93/kibana-3.0.0milestone5/#/dashboard/file/default.json] and load Kibana. Right now it does not load using .93; though it does work on .91.
The kibana config for .91 has elasticsearch: "http://"+window.location.hostname+":9200", which I know is not recommended but if I change it to the IP it does not load.
Kibana config for .93 is elasticsearch: "http://"+10.110.65.91+":9200",

Security groups are open.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `String + IP + String` could be whatever. Have you tried to put the entire URL as a string like: "http://10.110.65.91:9200"?

Comment: It loads using .91. I want it to be centralized on my logstash server of .93 so that I can go to http://10.110.65.93/kibana/whatever and load the web gui there vs using .91 which is an elasticsearch node. Basically I want .93 to index it all.

Comment: What is .91 running for webserver? Apache ? Nginx ?

Comment: Elasticsearch and apache. .93 is just running apache and some logstash shipper.conf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose I put the following in `config.js`:

```
elasticsearch: "http://"+127.0.0.1+":9200",
```

I then load Kibana's dashboard, which comes up blank. I go to check my browser's JavaScript console, and find two errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number (in config.js)
Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined (in app.js)
```

In a nutshell, Kibana fails to render because you gave it a config file that won't compile.

Suppose I try this, instead:

```
elasticsearch: "http://127.0.0.1:9200",
```

This compiles! Kibana renders! But then throws up a red error message:

```
Could not contact Elasticsearch at http://127.0.0.1:9200. Please ensure that Elasticsearch is reachable from your system.
```

Reason being: Kibana is resolving the IP address on the client machine, not the server; since my workstation isn't an ElasticSearch node, my browser cannot find an ES cluster at `127.0.0.1:9200`.

Kibana doesn't know about Logstash, and doesn't care, just as long as the rendered page can connect to an ES cluster at the address given. For your setup, that seems to be `http://10.110.65.91:9200` or `http://10.110.65.92:9200`. You could set up a proxy or firewall around those, whether for security, load balancing, or whatever.

Comment: Hate to revive this but I have my elasticsearch/kibana on behind an Elastic Load Balance with a public IP. I changed the config.js to elasticsearch: 'http://54.85.13.88:9200' which is the public IP of the ELB. Kibana loads but not the elasticsearch stuff. I've tried changing it to the local IP as well but just get the error "Error Could not contact Elasticsearch at http://54.85.13.88:9200. Please ensure that Elasticsearch is reachable from your system". What needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: Ugh, it was the security groups and elb listeners. Fixed.

Comment: @Gabriel, I did that: `elasticsearch: "http://54.xx.xx.xx:9200",` , but still, it doesn't show the rest of the page, it's an amazon instance, I'm not sure what did you do to make it work? shouldn't it work fine from any IP address?

Comment: FYI .. I can't view `ElasticSearch` in the first place from an external IP, regardless of Kibana, but I can query it locally

Comment: Elastic load balancer IP addresses change so it's better to use the actual URL rather than the IP. I didn't have my security groups and the listeners on the ELB updated properly. Once I did that I had it up and running. I'm working on a tutorial actually, once it's done I can link it here for you.